# How to boot to OS/Shell in Windows 10 IoT Core?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

Just getting started with Windows 10 IoT Core on Raspberry Pi 3.

It's not apparent to me how to simply boot to Windows rather than booting into an app (e.g. the defaultapp). **Maybe it's not possible?** I would expect this type of configuration with a microcontroller like Arduino, but was expecting a Command shell or PowerShell when booting into Windows on a Pi. I wasn't necessarily expecting a GUI or Desktop.

The command prompt in the default app doesn't really act like much of a command prompt. And I see no way to exit the default app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's not apparent to me how to simply boot to Windows rather than
>   booting into an app (e.g. the defaultapp). Maybe it's not possible?

No, it is by design. It will boot to the default app instead of Desktop like PC.

> I would expect this type of configuration with a microcontroller like
>   Arduino, but was expecting a Command shell or PowerShell when booting
>   into Windows on a Pi. I wasn't necessarily expecting a GUI or Desktop.

Then you can remote connect the device via [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/powershell) or [SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/ssh).

> The command prompt in the default app doesn't really act like much of
>   a command prompt.

Yes, it executing commands as DefaultAccount. If you require administrator access you can type "RunAsAdmin " in the command line prompt. For example:

`RunAsAdmin ping 192.168.10.1`